# Send File Path in order to choose the respective application to open in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, share

In my application I will have list with different file paths.
Example list:

1. /storage/emulated/0/Edited/myjpeg_file.JPG
2. /storage/emulated/0/Downloads/bill.pdf
3. /storage/emulated/0/Downloads/mytextfile.txt

This list is showed in list view. When I click on one entry, it should open list of supported installed applications to process it further.

When I click on entry wit .JPG then it should show apps related to that.
And If i select .pdf file it should show supported apps

And for all paths default it should show file browser such as default file manager , Es Explorer etc...

I am referring to
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

But need the selection based on file type (txt, xml, pdf jpeg etc..).
If i select .JPG file it is not showing gallery or Es file explorer (i have it on my mobile)
In same way when I click on .pdf file it is not showing adobe reader etc..

**Below is my code:**

```
    public void openFile(String minmeType, Uri uriFromPath) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriFromPath);
    if(minmeType.contains("text/plain")) {
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    } else {
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "sending out"));
```

}

**Above function is called from below code:**

```
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String path = pathList[position];
            Uri uriFromPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Uri: "+ uriFromPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(path.contains(".JPG")) {
                openFile("image/*", uriFromPath);
            } else {
                openFile("text/plain", uriFromPath);
            }
            return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ACTION_VIEW instead of ACTION_SEND?

ACTION_SEND implies you want to send the document to somebody else. Adobe Reader won't catch those Intents that want to do ACTION_SEND, because sending pdfs is not what they do. VIEWing them, on the other hand, is.

You also need to match the intent that the target application is filtering for.

In this case, it's pretty simple what you want to do: you want Adobe Reader to open your file. And Adobe Reader actually has the intent filter you would expect. If you look into its Manifest file, you'll see that (among others) it includes an intent filter that matches Uris with schema file, any host, and any path that ends in .pdf. If you change your openFile method to this:

```
    public void openFile(Uri uriFromPath) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriFromPath);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "sending out"));
    }
```

It will work. It should also work for most apps that handle content from files.

Comment: changing to ACTION_VIEW to ACTION_SEND is showing "no app can perform this action" for any file. Not showing any app.

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer to show a working solution.